# Compare the unique index value with another array in objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, arrays, nsmutablearray

There is an array having same objects in single array , i need to compare these array’s index with another array..  Give me a help.
  Something like:

```
 NSMutableArray *latArray  = 
       [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@“43.20,@“43.23”,@“43.24”,@“43.20”,nil];

 NSMutableArray *lngArray  = 
       [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@“76.90”,@“76.94”,@“76.92”,@“76.90”,nil];

 NSMutableArray *imagesArray = 
       [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1.jpg", @"2.jpg”,@“3.jpg”,@“4.jpg”,nil];

  resultResult  = @"1.jpg", @“4.jpg” // because the index 0 and index 3 same values in both array.
```

Comment: question is not clear, what do you want ..?

Comment: @saif: Check the same obj in array's and same index with another array, show the result of same index value comparing imagesarray.

Comment: Where does "5.jpg" come from?

Comment: You may be interested with this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757540/find-indices-of-duplicates-in-a-nsarray and maybe create therefore a new Array with `NSValue`/`CLLocationCoordinate2D` to actually use to compare.

Answer (score 0):

I would wrap your coordinates into location objects and use them as the keys in a dictionary. This would allow to check for duplicate coordinates, like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *results = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
for (int i = 0; i < [imagesArray count]; i++)
{
    // Wrap coordinates into a NSValue object
    // (CLLocationCoordinate2D is a C-struct that cannot be used as a dictionary key)
    // (CLLocation also does not implement required methods to be usable as a dictionary key)
    NSValue *loc = [NSValue valueWithMKCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(
        ((NSNumber)[latArray objectAtIndex:i]).doubleValue,
        ((double)[lngArray objectAtIndex:i]).doubleValue)];
    // 1. If you only want the first occurrence of a specific location, use this:
    if ([results objectForKey:loc] == nil)
    {
        [results setObject:[imagesArray objectAtIndex:i] forKey:loc];
    }
    // 2. Or, if you want the last occurrence of a specific location, use this:
    [results setObject:[imagesArray objectAtIndex:i] forKey:loc];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying the check for the same objects in an array. If so do the following.

```
for(int i=0;i<yourarray.count;i++)
  {
    NSString *yourstring=[yourarray objectatindex:i];
    for(int k=0;k<yourarray.count;k++)
    {
      if(i!=k)
      {
        NSString *yourstring2=[yourarray objectatindex:k];
        if([yourstring isEqualtostring yourstring2])
         {
           //now you got equal objects. do what ever you want here
          }
       }
     }
    }
```